# 500 Internal Server Error on /checkout/onepage/saveOrder/ redirects to cart without emptying

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, onepage-checkout, save

I am facing 500 Internal Server Error on /checkout/onepage/saveOrder/form_key/xxxx at the time of clicking place order button at checkout page.

I have found the same issue at this link http://forum.azmagento.com/how-to/500-internal-server-error-on-checkout-onepage-saveorder-redirects-to-cart-without-emptying-71292.html and they have mentioned PHP Memory limit is the problem.

My question is whether this is the apt solution for the issue or any other reason for this issue.

Please help me from this issue..

Comment: Please enable log from magento admin   and check  on log what are the issue

Comment: Thanks for the reply@AmitBera.. there is no issue at the log

Comment: Is there anything in your apache error logs?

Comment: @Astro : Does solve your problem ??

Comment: Yes. @JeevaRathinam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When enabling  `display_errors = 1` at `.user.ini` you got to know the error reason.then you can be able tosolve this