# 500-Internal-Server-Error-on-checkout-onepage-saveOrder

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout

I am facing 500 Internal Server Error on /checkout/onepage/saveOrder/form_key/xxxx at the time of clicking place order button at checkout page.
I have tried the solutions [link 1](https://community.magento.com/t5/Technical-Issues/500-Internal-Server-Error-on-checkout-onepage-saveOrder/td-p/17585) and [link 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/83955/500-internal-server-error-on-checkout-onepage-saveorder-redirects-to-cart-with)

When i print `mystore/info.php` it shows mbstring is enabled.
When enabling  `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at `index.php` it doesn't prints any of the errors.

How to solve this.

Comment: Have you checked the var/log/system.log and var/log/exception.log ? Also in the event that magento isn't being hit it would be worth checking your apache or nginx logs which should give you a more helpful error and specific file that is being problematic.

Comment: yes. I got `system_pri.log` and `exception_pri.log`. `system_pri.log` contains ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: _pageLayout and `exception_pri.log` contains ERR (3): 
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: '.

Comment: i guss that ini_set('display_errors', 1); doe not working for your case..  this code may be restrict by hosting provider

Comment: There should be more to those errors telling you which files have issues. Looks like you have a block that hasn't been created properly as you have an invalid block type and there is a pageLayout issue too.

Comment: Is the errors are related to my issue.

Comment: They could be, it depends on what the full error is. It could be a module that adds a block to the checkout, something in the theme, file permissions, without see the full errors it's hard to be specific.